# How to add callback/listner on textInput object (bokeh)?

Tags: python, bokeh

I have added a text input into my current document to parameterize one underlying sql query of mine through

```
textInput = TextInput(title="query_parameters", name='id', value='my sine wave')

curdoc().add(textInput)
```

how can I attach a listener/callback function to this textInput widget in current document ?